# Chrome - Selected Text - Right Click [LOOK UP] - How to disable

Tags: google-chrome, search, context-menu, right-click, lookup

After some recent update Chrome fro Mac got this SUPER ANNOYING feture. When you select text and right click it, menu comes up. I often used "Search Google for" but now the first thing in menu is LOOK UP which is useless and I have to do this second time... Please see attached image.

[image: Chrome Look Up - Right Click Menu]

Question is - how to disable this Look Up thing - Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it seems that this cannot be disabled.

The same question has been answered in https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/239459